# Updating Spatial Partition Info

Tags: c++

Right now I am developing a grid spatial partition to make 2d particles collisions. The thing is that I am not sure if there is a way to update the grid efficiently without having to reallocate the whole grid every frame. What I am doing now is to collect the objects from a object pool, putting them in their own cells and then allocating a new grid in the next frame as the grid is a local variable to the update function. There is a better way to implement this? And which type of container would you recommend me as I am using vector because it uses contiguous memory and using reserve. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just have 2 vectors 1 for the current data 1 for the next step. Keep the 2nd allocated while needed. (Eg make it a static member of the function) When you finished calculating the newt step call `swap` on the vectors, this way no re-allocation needed, but you have to have `2N` memory. (Also if the needed length is known call `resize` not `push_back`-s that is both faster and don't allocate more memory then needed)

Note: this is not strictly a `c++` question I don't even known if it is a "valid" stack-overflow question, because it will not be useful for later readers.